# Search files in s3 bucket using bucket with filename

Tags: file, search, amazon-s3, filenames, boto

Suppose I upload a file in a bucket and there are already some 1000 files in the same bucket. Now i would like to search files through the filename if its there in the bucket or not. Help is appreciated. as I was unable to find any such documentation. If anyone has tried this then do post you comments :)

Comment: Are you using any of the s3 client apis?

Comment: no i just wanted to retrieve the file using boto script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no search functionality in the S3 API.  If you know the exact name of the file you can issue a HEAD request to that object in the S3 bucket (the boto lookup() method does this) and if you get a 200 Response back from the server then you know the file is there.  If you get a 404, it's not there.

If you don't know the exact name of the file you are looking for, all you can really do is list the contents of the bucket until you find the file you are looking for.  This is very inefficient and if you need to do this on a regular basis, I would recommend storing the filenames in a separate database that would allow you to search efficiently.

Comment: I believe it is possible to request the names of the keys in the bucket where the keys start with a specific prefix.